# How to remove data from header menu and add new content to it in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am working with magento.
I have been trying to remove the content from header-menu and add fresh content like

```
    **HOME    ABOUTUS    SITES    CONTACT**
```

Here is the current situation, 
[image]

[image]
**Update**
Above is the screen shot that follows after the top-menu
Please guide me to achieve this..
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the above menutimes that you've shown in the image are categories. So if you don't need it on the top menu then go to each of the categories (under Catalog -> Manage Categories) in the backend / admin panel and choose "NO" as an value to the option "**Include in Navigation Menu**". This will remove them from the navigation top menu.

And to bring these menu items

HOME ABOUTUS  SITES

Let me describe it for one of the items above. Lets take **About Us**

1. At first create the respective **CMS static block** for "About Us"
2. Create a **category** called "About Us"
3. Go to display settings of the About Us category and choose the display mode as "**static block only**" and then select the static block "about us"
4. **Save the category and reload your page** on the frontend/website

you can find the "**about us**" category on the top menu and opening it will show the content from the static block.

Repeat the same for the other menu items.

If this helps mark it as answer. Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the top menu list is displayed as left navigation. So if i choose "NO" as a value to the option "Include in Navigation Menu" the list is disappearing in left navigation also. I only want to remove top menu.                                                 please check my updated question with the image

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't want categories in top menu. In place of it you want Custom links like "Home", "About us" etc.

For this open topmenu.phtml file in template->page->html.
In this commented the below line :-

```
 <?php echo $_menu ?>
```

and in place of it call a static block of name "custom_top_nav" :-

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('custom_top_nav')->toHtml() ?>
```

In this block you can make your custom menu.

We you want both custom links plus categories then you can replace code with this:-

```
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>
  <?php if($_menu): ?>
    <div class="nav-container">
        <ul id="nav">
           <li class="home"><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('home');?>"> HOME </a> </li>
             <?php echo $_menu ?>
         </ul>
       </div>
    <?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Magento hide categories in the header menu** - This can be done from your Admin Panel under Manage Categories > To do this is easy if you don't want your categories in top menu of your web site - When you add a new Category Select no for > Include in Navigation Menu * Its under Meta Description at the bottom of the page where you add the the Category name in General Information Tab*